what is the correct way to develop a NFT minting
I'm a learner of dapp developing, I have learned some steps to do before minting a NFT:

submit a form in frontend, send image file and other fields like name, description etc. to backend;

the backend server recieves request, upload image file to ipfs and get the image CID, build metadata with image CID and other fields in request, then upload the metadata json file to ipfs and get metadata CID;

send a transaction to blockchain, invoke mint(address, 'ipfs://CID') function of the smart contract;


my question is:
where to do step 3 work, frontend or backend?

If frontend, I need to return the metadata CID to the page, how to promise the NFT is minted successfully by the real owner, I mean if then failing to send transaction, and others find this NFT metadata file in the ipfs so they can mint it with the CID but they are not the real author? or maybe other problems exist?
If backend, how to get users' sign from frontend, how can the metamask will popup to ask user to sign the tx? how to send signed tx to the backend and then backend send to blockchain.

what's the popular way?
